# How to avoid jumping content between frames with overlayarea and frames without overlayarea?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, overlays

In my slide deck, I have some frames that use `overlayarea` and some that don't. Regardless of whether a frame uses `overlayarea` or not, I want all text content to start at exactly the same position from the top. But it looks like whenever I use an `overlayarea`, it shifts the text even if I use the `t` option for all frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

% Frame 1
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame 1}
Content 1
\end{frame}

% Frame 2
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame 2}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{20mm}
Content 2
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here are two frames:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Open both the images in two new tabs and switch between them to see the jumping around of the content.

How can I avoid this jumping around of content between frames with `overlayarea` and frames without `overlayarea`?

Comment: basically: reconsider your setup. overlayarea is a large box with a large height, and it is difficult to generally align the inner content to something. overlayarea is useful for graphics, but not for running text.

Comment: Can you add some background information why you are using the `overlayarea` environment? There might be other ways to get your desired result.